# Ipv6 routers for home and smb

Tags: router, ipv6, smb

Keep reading stories about how ipv4 is just about out of addresses and how we need to start moving to ipv6

What kind of hardware is out there and what features desirable for SMB and or home use?

Comment: I want to make this a community wiki but don't seem to have the ability ????  And if this is a dupe notify me and I will move to delete.

Comment: It shouldn't be a CW, but it should be on SU. We'll move it automatically. Good question though, I've just grown accustom to rolling my own routers to get around the shortcomings of what's on the marketplace.

Comment: for what it's worth, those stories have been running for ever and a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/IPv6) offers IPv6 support, and works on a variety of hardware that wasn't originally designed for it.

One thing you will find a problem with is that there is a distinct lack of IPv6 sites out there, and few ISPs route IPv6 traffic, so you can't use **end-to-end** IPv6. However, in order to simulate it within your own network, use 6to4. It will act like you're using IPv6 (all your network computers will think they're using it), but it will actually be on IPv4 over the network. Once IPv6 is supported by ISPs and websites, then the switch is easy! DD-WRT offers support for end-to-end and 6to4.

Comment: +1 for dd-wrt; been using it since it was in beta and love it. Would +2 for stating that few ISPs can actually handle IPv6. @MikeJ, don't worry too much. When your ISP needs to start using IPv6 they'll push hardware on you.

Comment: I use DD-wrt here at home. I hadnt upgraded in a long time, so I wasn't aware that it would be able to support ipv6. Yes, I suspect my ISP might push ipv6 hardware on me, but sometimes they give us junk like the SMC modem/router combo.

Answer (score 1):

There are some answers (from the ISP's point of view) over on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/195270/what-ipv6-cpe-is-available) but the basic answer seems to be that IPv6 support in a SoHo router is still very unusual, but you can try:

DD-WRT

AVM Fritz!Box

Draytek Vigor

If you're prepared to pay about five times as much, then the Cisco 887W (or 886W if you're in an Annex B country like Germany) will definitely work.

There is also the alternative of something like a Draytek Vigor 120, which is a pure modem and then setting up a PPPoE connection from a computer.  You could use one of the many router/firewall Linux distros with the modem and then have a switch and an AP.

Effectively, that would divide up the five components of the standard home router into four pieces (DSL modem - firewall/router - ethernet switch - wireless access point).